# 500 Internal Error Debugging

Tags: php

Hi I have been trying to debug the internal 500 error for my website but I am failing to figure out the cause of the error.

error Link: https://www.hand-made.com.au/search?q=bags

> Error: 500 Internal Error

I have tried to edit my php.ini file but no error is displaying

also where will my error be shown?

**PHP.ini**

```
<?php
     error_reporting(E_ALL);
     ini_set('display_errors', 1);

?>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: on your server `error.log` files will be there somewhere, check those and you will come to know the problem.

Comment: Do you have change in .htaccess file ?

Comment: Hi on my error log. I am seeing this error

[Tue Feb 23 16:00:10.325045 2016] [:error] [pid 10481] [client 66.249.71.71:33715] PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in /home/handmade/public_html/php.ini on line 4
[Tue Feb 23 16:00:10.163479 2016] [:error] [pid 10480] [client 157.55.39.50:20671] PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in /home/handmade/public_html/php.ini on line 4
[Tue Feb 23 16:00:07.793687 2016] [:error] [pid 9247] [client 68.180.228.219:55084] PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in /home/handmade/public_html/php.ini on line 4

Comment: Mehdi no I didn't touch my .htaccess file

Comment: Your logs seem to indicate that there's a problem with the `php.ini` file on line 4. It seems you have an unexpected `(` on that line.

Comment: Can you tell me how do I fix this error?

Comment: remove syntax error if any,use this --> error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); ini_set('display_errors', 'on'); at top of your view file. see htaccess file if you did any change.

Comment: @Meganglenn From what you've shown - delete the `(` on line 4 of your `php.ini` file.  Or.. edit the question to show some of the `php.ini` file.

Comment: Jon I have added php.ini in my question please check

Comment: @Meganglenn That's not the `php.ini` file, that's a `php` file that is executed. if using the command prompt, your `php.ini` file is located at `/home/handmade/public_html/php.ini` and if what you have posted right now is in your `php.ini` file, then the setup is wrong.

Comment: This is where I am editing my php.ini /home/handmade/public_html/php.ini file can you please help me out to fix this problem?

Comment: remove mentioned code from your php.ini file and put display_errors=On

Answer (score 0):

To display error just place the code below on the top of your page.

```
<?php
     error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

And the replace your php.ini file with the original php.ini file.

Comment: Did you replace your php.ini file with the original file??

Comment: i dont get it what do you mean by original file but I posted the above lines into my empty php.ini file but nothing happend

Comment: Find the php.ini file for your current PHP version and replace the empty file with that file.
And paste the above code on the top of the page where you want to display the errors.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of a previous copy of your website loaded in your browser. Most of the time 500 error is resolved by refreshing the page. If it doesn't resolve the problem. Try clearing the cache and removing the saved cookies and then refresh the page. If the problem still persists. Please share your relevant code.

Comment: cleaned my browser cache but no luck! currently my php.ini is empty

Comment: It shouldn't be empty. Please check if you have downloaded two versions of php. Also use the default php.ini.